# Raspberry Pi 2 with Caffe protobuf error

Tags: protocol-buffers, caffe, raspberry-pi2

Has anyone successfuly launched Caffe on Raspberry Pi 2? I installed OpenCV and Caffe without errors (eventually). But when i launch my C++ code that uses OpenCV and Caffe, it throws this error:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:57] File already exists in database: caffe.proto
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1018] CHECK failed: generated_database_->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  CHECK failed: generated_database_->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
Aborted
```

I tried installing a newer protobuf version, but that did not help. Some suggested that this is due to using dynamic libs, but this C++ code runs fine on other devices in GPU and CPU mode. It uses about 600MB of RAM and the R. Pi had 822MB of free RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuilding opencv with -D BUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF and then rebuilding caffe solved the issue. However i'm not sure if i don't use the opencv_dnn library.

Comment: This helped me as well! Thanks